# Update button in PHP/Mysql needs to clicked twice in order to work?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, mysqli

I am fairly new to php and sql trying to figure out to get the form button to be only be clicked once to update. The program already has an add, search, and delete working just fine and just need to get this to work. It seems to be updating, but it doesn't output the update until I click again. Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['update']) &&
    isset($_POST['name']) &&
    isset($_POST['planet']) &&
    isset($_POST['country']) &&
    isset($_POST['population']) &&
    isset($_POST['density']))
{
    $name = get_post($conn, 'name');
    $planet  = get_post($conn, 'planet');
    $country = get_post($conn, 'country');
    $population = get_post($conn, 'population');
    $density = get_post($conn, 'density');
    $sql = "UPDATE cities SET planet = '$planet', country = '$country',     population = '$population', density = $density WHERE name = '$name' ;";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);
}
echo <<<_END
<pre>
    name $row[0]
    planet $row[1]
    country $row[2]
    population $row[3]
    density $row[4]
</pre>
<form action="Hw05.php" method="post"><pre>
    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="yes">
    name <input type="text" name="name" value="$row[0]">
    planet <input type="text" name="planet" value="$row[1]">
    country <input type="text" name="country" value="$row[2]">
    population <input type="int" name="population" value="$row[3]">
    density <input type="int" name="density" value="$row[4]">
    <input type="submit" value="UPDATE RECORD">
</pre></form>
 _END;
```

Any help would be appreciated, like I am said I am new to Php/mysql and more of a Java guy. (However I do like php).

Comment: From where is your `$row` coming? You didn't define that in anywhere. And also in your code the heredoc `_END` has a space infront of it. There should not be any spece before heredoc ending and there must be a new line after just ending heredoc.

Answer (score 0):

The query that stores data in `$row` is not in your code, so I think this query is done before the UPDATE query. You should make your SELECT query after your UPDATE, because data in $row is selected before that you update table.

Comment: Initialize it above isset and still needs to be updated twice.                 $rows = $result->num_rows;

Comment: @bobbert_the_adventurer Just move your SELECT query after the isset block. I think you are not using $row before your isset block :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables might be populated before the update happens. You need to do a SELECT query again to get the updated values.